# Помогите, с каким графическим компонентом я могу реализовать подобный дизайн?

Tags: javascript

Я только недавно столкнулся с Ext.js, сегодня дизайнер предоставил макет для формы редактирования доп полей. В данном макете представлено поле со списком значений, как и с помощью чего можно реализовать это на ext?

[image]

Comment: А теперь на русском, так как вы на ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Я только недавно столкнулся с Ext.js, сегодня дизайнер предоставил макет для формы редактирования доп полей. В данном макете представлено поле со списком значений, как и с помощью чего можно реализовать это на ext?.

Comment: Это оказался Tagfield, вопрос можно закрыть

Comment: @Lex вопрос закрывать не стоит, как и удалять. Лучше ответьте сами на свой вопрос названием компонента, кратким описанием, приложите ссылки на документацию и приведите примеры реализации (если они есть). Так вы поможете другим пользователям, которые столкнуться с подобной проблемой. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это оказался Tagfield - поле тегов, документацию по нему можно найти [здесь](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html)